# Tags in WinForms TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to create a textbox on a WinForms form, where the user cannot input text directly. Instead, the content of the textbox should only be "bubbles" (with a "delete" button), showing a text value.

I'm struggeling to find the correct term for this kind of control/behaviour. It should look a bit like the "Tags"-field on StackOverflow when creating a new question.

Are there any existing controls/settings that allow such behaviour? (I have DevExpress if that helps)

Sorry for the vague question, if i knew better terms for what i'm looking for, i'd probably find something...

Comment: I've created something like this from scratch before by heavily extending the existing `TextBox` control, custom painting, heavy interception of the various Key-based events, and various trickery with a lot of comments. I cannot post the code, just wanted to let you know that it is possible if you're determined enough.

Comment: Alright, i'll keep that in mind if i want to extend the "textbox" :-)

Comment: Please share the snippet if you were able to found any?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of a textbox, the container for your bubbles should most likely be a Panel.
You can style it as needed, set the border, background color, etc.
If you don't want to manually position the "bubbles" inside it, use a FlowLayoutPanel. It will automatically put it's children controls in a flow.
Check out the properties of the control to specify how you want controls to be laid out.

The individual bubbles can also be Panels or other container controlls, so that you can add a label and a button (or image to serve as a button) to each.
You might even extend the panel class to automatically add a label and a delete button to each.

something like this (please note this is more like pseudo code. I wrote it up of the top of my head here, some adjustment may be needed)

```
Public Bubble : Panel {

  Public Bubble(string text) {
    Label title = new Label { Text = text };
    Controls.Add(title);

    Button delete = new Button { Text = "Delete" };
    Controls.Add(delete);

    //also hook up events here, ie delete.click+= whatever

  }

}
```

You can further extend the custom class for your specific needs.
Set styles on the button and label as needed to achive the look you want.
Don't forget to hook up events such as mouse over, button click, etc.

Then just fill the FlowLayoutPanel with these custom controls and you should be good to go

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Sometimes the brain is so clogged, that the easiest answer just doesn't come to mind. A FlowLayoutPanel + some tiny bubble control works perfectly ;-)

Comment: No problem! Glad to be of help. Consider marking the answer as the correct solution.

Comment: Of course ;-) I was building a prototype and didn't get around to marking it yet